# Object Detection versus Accident Avoidance

Tags: object-detection, anylogic

I acknowledge  that I have used the sample codes that @Benjamin used in different examples.

I want to have both object detection numbers and accident numbers in my model. I need a code to detect object. But object detection does not necessarily lead to an accident. When an object is detected the agent(transporter) should either stop or change its route.  The following code is about this functionality. `field of view` is a polygonal in front of the transporter.

```
for (Worker thisPed: main.worker) {
//for each pedestrain in model

double pedX = thisPed.getX() -getX(); 
double pedY = thisPed.getY() -getY();
if (fieldOfView.contains(pedX, pedY)) {
v_pedInDanger = true; 
setSpeed(0);
break; 
}
}
```

How to tell transporter to change route instead of stop? I could not find a code in this regard.

However,  I should use another code to calculate distance between transporter and the detected object and if the `distance <= 1 METER` then we count it as an accident. like the following:

```
for (Worker ped: main.worker){
double dist = 0; 
dist = distanceTo(ped);

if (dist <= 1){
v_pedCollisionNumber += 1; 
ped.v_isWorkerCollide = true; 
send ("accident", this);  
}
}
```

the second one does not work.

Any Advise please? Any better approach?

Comment: For route changing, you can find the relative position of the person wrt the object. If the object is on the left side when compared with the person (based on the coordinates), you can make the object go right (if you can), otherwise just make it stop and vice versa.  

You probably can build/modify this as you see fit

Comment: Hi @Jitesh,  I am not sure if I completely understood your approach. Would you please provide more details? Thank you very much.